# LocalDate data type in Java

Tags: java, date, types, simpledateformat

I am working on an assignment where we are creating our own classes with their own attributes and methods (Constructor, Getter and Setter) and for one class I will need some attributes that use date e.g. dateOfIssue or dateOfPayment. I am trying to use the new LocalDate data type, but when I have instantiated an object from CheckingAccount and try to set a date, I don't know what format to put it in. I have tried 3 ints, e.g. 05, 06, 2010 in different orders, but it says  expected.

Can anyone help?

```
import java.time.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

final public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
    //Attributes
    private int checkingBookNo;
    private BigDecimal amountLastCheck;
    private LocalDate dateOfIssue;


public CheckingAccount(){
    checkingBookNo = 0;
    dateOfIssue = null;

}

public void setDateOfIssue ( LocalDate dateOfIssueIn )
{
   dateOfIssue = dateOfIssueIn;
}
}
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is for parsing a `String` to `Date` or formatting a `Date` to `String`. To store a date you have to use `Date` type as `SimpleDateFormat` won't store you any specific date value.

Comment: Java's Date data types suck hard. Use jodatime instead. Always. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 supplants `java.util.Date` and instead provides a much improved new [Date and Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html). If the use of Java 8 is prohibited, but the use of 3rd party libraries is permitted, the [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is a great option. This library was the basis for the new Java 8 Date and Time API, and can be used with earlier versions of Java.

---

In case of using Java 8 [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the property should be of type [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (or [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is the time portion is needed). Setter and getter should accept and return object of the same type respectively.

Here're a couple of examples how to create date instances:

```
// the current date
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();

// 2015-02-11
LocalDate tenthFeb2014 = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.FEBRUARY, 11);
```

A nice tutorial on Java 8 Date/Time API is available [here](http://www.mscharhag.com/2014/02/java-8-datetime-api.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Plus 1 for pointing out that old Java Date sucks and showing the better options.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. :) I've made an edit to my code now, but I'm still fairly clueless quite how to go about using this LocalDate type and it's format? E.g. when doing this thing with a String, I can use a setter method and type in the string like "John" and John will be stored for that object and I can use a getter method to return the string. This is what I want for the date. Any ideas?

Comment: **Correction** Java 8 certainly does *not* deprecate java.util.Date. Parts of java.util.Date are indeed deprecated, but that occurred years before Java 8. Perhaps you meant the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package supplants java.util.Date/.Calendar classes, making them outmoded – That certainly is true.

Comment: @BasilBourque The old date API is not deprecated in a sense that all classes and methods are marked as depricated. However, I do think the term is applicable in the given context (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation).

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. But your terminology is simply wrong. Examine the definition given in the link you provide. The old classes are not disapproved by Oracle, the JCP, nor [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). The implementation of java.time was built to be compatible to and fro, as were related classes such as java.sql.Timestamp. Neither the documentation nor the source code is not marked as deprecated. There has been no warning that the classes will be removed in the future. *Deprecation* has a specific technical meaning, and that term does not apply in this case.

Comment: @BasilBourque Agreed. In order to avoid any confusion the response has been adjusted. Tank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've kind of misunderstood the meaning of `SimpleDateFormat`.

This field should be of type `Date` not of type `SimpleDateFormat`.

`private SimpleDateFormat dateOfIssue;`

The same goes for its setter's parameter. A `SimpleDateFormat` object
is not a date, it's something which allows you to parse/format
`Date`s from/to `String`s. So that's the root cause of your problem.